# Wiring a ceiling light fixture after discovering it was tripping a circuit

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

One of my circuits has been tripping for the last few weeks. I troubleshot all of the outlets and switches. I started working on my ceiling light and found a discolored wire. White wire with black electrical tape wrapped all around it but it had some brown discoloration. The white colored sheath was also split going all the way up with some tarnish around the copper wire. Not good I believe. I split everything up and attempted to reset the breaker, which held. I suspect that this is the problem.

But I'm having some trouble rewiring it. There are 4 two-wire in the junction box. I'm assuming it's source, two branches, and a switch loop but I'm not sure.

Can you guys make any sense of the box and advise on how complete the wiring? The discoloration in the  damaged wire in the picture below is from adhesive from black tape being wrapped around it.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide photos of the inside of the switch box that controlled this light?

Comment: Did you take a picture before you took everything apart?

Comment: I did not take a picture.

Comment: I've also added the switches that control the light. There are only two.

Comment: It is possible the white wire with black tape was for a switch leg. Code has required a “switch leg” where the always hot is fed to a switch to be remarked or identified with a color other than white green or grey. So be aware that white may be a wire that is supposed to go to an always hot, the only way to know is to trace the wires that is what an electrician would have to do.